# Want to test ebay site login without using Xpath

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, java, firefoxdriver, css-selectors

[image]

I want to test the Ebay site login, without using `Xpath`. It is not working, right now. I tried for hours to make this work. Please tell me what I am doing wrong and how to fix it.

This is what I am doing:

1. Open Google website
2. Search for “ebay” website
3. Click on the appropriate result
4. Go to http://www.ebay.com website
5. Click on the “Sign in” link to navigate to the ebay login page
6. Enter email address/password
7. Click on Sign In button
8. Verify your user name.

---

```
package Script;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class TestEbay_login {
    @Test
    public void ebay_login() throws InterruptedException {

            System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Users\\Senani\\Downloads\\Programs\\geckodriver-v0.23.0-win64\\geckodriver.exe");
            WebDriver driver = new  FirefoxDriver();
            //driver.get("https://www.google.com");
            driver.navigate().to("https://www.google.com");
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
            driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys("ebay");
            driver.findElement(By.name("btnK")).submit();
            driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[href='www.ebay.com']")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.linkText("Sign in")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.id("userid")).sendKeys("*******");
            driver.findElement(By.id("pass")).sendKeys("*******");

            driver.findElement(By.id("sgnBt")).click();
    }
}
```

> FAILED: ebay_login org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable
>   to locate element: a[href='www.ebay.com'] For documentation on this
>   error, please visit:
>   https://www.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html Build info:
>   version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time:
>   '2018-11-14T08:25:48'

**update question** how to find unique anything this element. Can anyone help me. I'm stuck in this code.

```
<a href="https://www.ebay.com/" ping="/url?sa=t&amp;source=web&amp;rct=j&amp;url=https://www.ebay.com/&amp;ved=2ahUKEwjDpP21_c_fAhWLLY8KHXYwB9gQFjAAegQIAxAC">
    <h3 class="LC20lb">eBay: Electronics, Cars, Fashion, Collectibles, Coupons and More</h3>
    <br>
    <div style="display:inline-block" class="TbwUpd">
        <cite class="iUh30">https://www.ebay.com/</cite>
    </div>
</a>
```

Comment: above code I tried

Comment: so nothing. the error states Unable to locate element: a[href='www.ebay.com'], so that element must not be on the page

Comment: reason is i cannot understand how to get the above image ebay link

Comment: so find a unique identifying attribute for the link, use the dev console?

Comment: update my question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87770/discussion-between-poorna-senani-gamage-and-doug-clark).

Comment: @PoornaSenaniGamage, I appreciate this is just a test account - but you might want to consider not putting your ebay username and password on the internet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks live you've answered your own question

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[href='www.ebay.com']"))
```

but the DOM says that element is

```
<a href="https://www.ebay.com/" ..../>
```

So update your code to reflect this different href *exactly*